# Spring Session 2.0 Redis Lettuce Configuration

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-session, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I'm attempting to integration Spring Session 2.0 w/ Redis into a spring framework webapp, but I'm getting caught on configuring the LettuceConnectionFactory. I need to configure it to use SSL, and Spring's documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis:reactive:connectors:lettuce) shows configuration like this:

```
LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
.useSsl().and()
.commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
.shutdownTimeout(Duration.ZERO)
.build();
```

However, the javadoc for LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceClientConfiguration.LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder.html) shows that the .useSsl() method actually returns a LettuceSslClientConfiguration ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceClientConfiguration.LettuceSslClientConfigurationBuilder.html)) and that has zero methods on it, and the LettuceConnectionFactory doesn't even accept it as a parameter ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceConnectionFactory.html)).

I'm wondering if this is a lapse in the api for Spring Data 2.0, but I can't find any bug reports. Any help is appreciated. I've tried to scour all their documentation, but it's very possible I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: can you please share dependencies which you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug which is going to be fixed with [DATAREDIS-755](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-755).

With Spring Data Redis 2.0 we introduced [immutable configuration objects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceClientConfiguration.java) to [LettuceConnectionFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceConnectionFactory.java). This change does not break existing functionality. That said, continue to use the deprecated methods until it's shipped.

If you don't use [LettuceClientConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceClientConfiguration.java) you there's no difference in behavior. If you use the new configuration object `LettuceClientConfiguration` and then call a deprecated setter method, this will raise an exception.